# Use path to an executable as an argument for a runner in CLion

Tags: build, cmake, clion

I have a CMake project in CLion. I am able to build my executable `hello`.

Now I want to run it inside CLion with a custom runner `mpirun` (it is an MPI project).

Bash command should look like: `mpirun -n 5 path_to_hello_executabe/hello`

How can I obtain this `path_to_hello_executabe` inside CLion configuration?

In CMake it looks like `add_custom_target(run $ENV{MPIRUN} -n 5 $<TARGET_FILE:hello>)`, so what I need is an equivalent for `$<TARGET_FILE:hello>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Configure build output path in Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake settings. So you know the path_to_hello_executabe now.
2. Add custom command in your CMake that will be executed during build. Then build the corresponding configuration in CLion. Your command will be called then.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible for now in CLion, since CLion's configurations can't run a command from add_custom_target cmake command. However this looks like an interesting use case and a nice feature to have: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5831

Comment: Any workaround? I am sure there is a syntax to get environment/build variables in the build configuration; I just can't discover it

Comment: Yes, see another answer here.

Comment: off-topic: I was lucky you saw my twit and replayed fast, but it would be nice to have a more consistent way of *fast* communication with the devs. For example see how the Kotlin guys use slack - we (users) find help there any time of a day from different team members in minutes!

Comment: @voddan You can always ping us via support https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us. Our developers will be glad to help. And we answer quick enough.
Or ping clion_ide twitter for short questions.